# A weakly modular function $f$ is a modular form if and only if $f$ is bounded in the fundamental domain

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, modular-forms

We consider modular functions/forms for $SL_2(\Bbb Z)$. I was asked to prove that

> A weakly modular function $f$ is a modular form if and only if $f$ is bounded in the fundamental domain $D$.

A function $f: \Bbb H\to\Bbb C$ is said to be a weakly modular function of (even) weight $k$ if $f$ is meromorphic on $\Bbb H$ and satisfies
$$f\left(\frac{az+b}{cz+d} \right) = (cz+d)^k f(z) \quad \forall \begin{pmatrix}a & b\\c& d \end{pmatrix} \in SL_2(\Bbb Z)$$
The fundamental domain $D$ is given by
$$D = \left\{z\in \Bbb H: \frac{-1}2 \le \operatorname{Re}z\le \frac12, |z| \ge 1 \right\}$$
and
a function $f: \Bbb H\to\Bbb C$ is said to be a modular form of weight $k$ if $f$ is a weakly modular function of weight $k$, and it is holomorphic everywhere on $\Bbb H\cup \{\infty\}$. How should I go about proving the claim? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If I understand correctly, a weakly modular form is a "modular form" that could have poles.
However, if the function is bounded in the neighborhood of a pole, then the singularity is removable and there is no pole at all. Would that suffice?

Comment: @GiulioR Could you please provide more details, possibly in an answer? If $f$ is bounded in its fundamental domain, is it clear that $f$ is bounded near every pole? I believe we are using Riemann's removable singularity theorem at this point. For the other direction, if $f$ is a modular form, how does it follow that $f$ is bounded in $D$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If $f$ is modular (which, by definition, implies that $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb H\cup\{\infty\}$) then $f$ is, in particular, continuous on $D\cup\{\infty\}$, which is compact. Hence $f$ is bounded on $D\cup\{\infty\}$ and so it is bounded on $D$.
2. Conversely, if $f$ is weakly modular and bounded in $D$ then we aim to show that $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb H\cup\{\infty\}$. First, as you say, Riemann's theorem on removable singularities tells us that there are no poles in $D\cup\{\infty\} $. Then, for any $z\in\mathbb H$ we can write $z=\frac{aw+b}{cw+d}$ with $w\in D$ and $\begin{pmatrix} a& b\\ c&d\end{pmatrix}\in SL_2(\mathbb Z)$. Then,
   $$
   f(z)=(cw+d)^kf(w).
   $$
   If $w$ is in the interior of $D$ we are done, as this shows that $f(z)$ is bounded in a neighborhood of $z$, and we can rule out the existence of poles by Riemann's theorem again(*).
   If $w$ is on the boundary, we can anyway cover a full neighborhood of $w$ by finitely many elements of $SL_2(\mathbb Z)$ and so the argument proceeds similarly.

EDIT: (*) If $w$ is in the interior of $D$, let $w\in U\subset D$ with $U$ open and bounded and let $V$ be the image of $U$ under $w\mapsto\frac{aw+b}{cw+d}$. Then $V$ is an open neighborhood of $z$ on which $f$ is bounded: indeed, if $z'\in V$, then there is $w'\in U$ such that
$$
f(z') = f(w')(cw'+d)^k
$$
which is bounded for all $z'\in V$ because $f$ is bounded on $U$ and because $U$ is bounded. Hence, we have shown that there exists an open neighborhood (namely, $V$) of any point $z\in\mathbb H$ on which $f$ is bounded. (Strictly speaking, as mentioned above, one has to reason slightly differently for points $z$ whose representative in $D$ lies on the boundary of $D$, but that is completely analogous.) Thus any singularity of $f$ on the upper half-plane $\mathbb H$ must be removable.

EDIT(2).

1. The map $w\mapsto \frac{aw+b}{cw+d}$ is an homeomorphism of the Riemann sphere, hence it is an open map (all homeomorphisms are!). Alternative argument: use the *open mapping theorem* in complex analysis, cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(complex_analysis)
2. It is convenient to recall the following fact: if $z_0$ is a pole of a meromorphic function $f$, then $\lim_{z\to z_0}|f(z)|=+\infty$ **for any path** $z\to z_0$. Then, also points at the boundary of $D$ cannot be poles of $f$ (as you can always approach $z\to z_0\in\partial D$ by a path entirely contained in $D$). I apologize, this argument is easier than the hinted one about covering a neighborhood of such points by finitely many $SL_2(\mathbb Z)$-orbits of $D$.
3. Holomorphicity at $\infty$. The fact that $f$ is bounded on $D$, along with the periodicity $f(z+1)=f(z)$, implies that that $f(z)$ is bounded on any half-plane $\Im z\geq k>0$. This ensures holomorphicity at $\infty$ in the usual sense for modular forms.

Comment: I don't understand the second part, that is, when you show that $f$ is holomorphic at every $z \in \Bbb H$ using $f(z)=(cw+d)^kf(w)$. Could you elaborate this bit further? Thanks!

Comment: 1. I guess Riemann's theorem ensures that there are no poles in $D$, but doesn't necessarily say anything about $D \cup \{\infty\}$, right? We only know that $f$ is bounded on $D$, so $f(\infty)$ could blow up unless we show it doesn't.

Comment: 2. Why is $V$ open? It's not clear that the map $w \mapsto \frac{aw+b}{cw+d}$ is open.

Comment: 3. *"If $w$ is on the boundary, we can anyway cover a full neighborhood of $w$ by finitely many elements of $SL_2(\mathbb Z)$..."* - what does this mean, and why is it true?

Comment: 1. If $f$ is bounded in $D$, it is bounded in $D\cup\{\infty\}$ as well, by continuity.
2. The map $w\to\frac{aw+b}{cw+d}$ is a biholomorphism, hence open. (See also this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(complex_analysis))
3. Suppose $w$ lies on either of the lines $\Re w=\pm 1/2$: it's enough to consider the map $w\mapsto w\pm 1$, to cover a neighboorhood of $w$ by $D$ and $D\pm 1$. Other points on the boundary can be treated similarly. If you need more details, I will add them (later when I have time).

Comment: I have added a few comments, let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I understand $(1)$ and $(2)$, but not the argument about holomorphicity at infinity. I see that $f$ is bounded in the half plane $H_k = \{z\in \Bbb H: \operatorname{Im} z \ge k\}$ for every $k\ge 1$, but what after that? Here are my thoughts: if we approach $\infty$ along any path in $\Bbb H$, the path must eventually lie in $H_k$, and so $f$ is bounded along the said path. As a result, $\lim_{z\to\infty} f(z)$ is bounded, and $\infty$ is not a pole. I am not sure if this makes sense or is rigorous enough; as I am thinking of $\infty$ as $i \infty$. Is that true?

Comment: You are right. It would be helpful to know exactly what type of condition you are assuming at $\infty$ when you say that a modular form is holomorphic at $\infty$. Indeed, $\infty$ is not an interior point in our domain (that is, probably, why you are thinking of $\infty$ as "$i\infty$") so that it is not enough to just say "holomorphic at $\infty$". E.g., in Zagier's book ("The 1-2-3 of modular forms", first half of page 5) the definition is that $f(x+iy)$ is bounded as $y\to+\infty$. This condition is indeed ensured if $f$ is bounded on $D$, because of the invariance under $z\mapsto z+1$.